# Reference an element of an array using a variable in Actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have a bunch of arrays (Q001, Q002, Q003...). Each array is a question plus 4 possible answers. I want to randomly choose which question to display. So I randomly assign an array name to the variable chosenQuestion. Then I try to write the first element of that array into a text box, like so:
txt.Question.text = [chosenQuestion][0];

For example, if the the chosen question is Q001 then it puts Q001 in the text box. But I really want in the text box is the first element of the array Q001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed that you have your 3 arrays of questions, so to get the question, you can do like this :

```
var question_01:Array = ['question 01', 'answer 01', 'answer 02', 'answer 03', 'answer 04'];
var question_02:Array = ['question 02', 'answer 01', 'answer 02', 'answer 03', 'answer 04'];
var question_03:Array = ['question 03', 'answer 01', 'answer 02', 'answer 03', 'answer 04'];

var selected_question:int = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);   // gives : 1, 2 or 3

trace(this['question_0' + selected_question][0]);   // gives : question 01, for example
```

You can also put your questions arrays into an array like this :

```
var questions:Array = [
    ['question 01', 'answer 011', 'answer 02', 'answer 03', 'answer 04'],
    ['question 02', 'answer 012', 'answer 02', 'answer 03', 'answer 04'],
    ['question 03', 'answer 013', 'answer 02', 'answer 03', 'answer 04']
];
selected_question = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);  // gives : 0, 1 or 2

trace(questions[selected_question][0]); // gives : question 02, for example
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you akomozo. You are AWESOME! I was missing the "this". The multidimensional array is a great solution too. Now I have two options.